# symfony 1.4 propel:build-all not working on Mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, symfony1, innodb, propel

i am using Symfony 1.4.8 and Mysql 5.5
 i got this error when i run

symfony propel:build-all

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ‘Type=InnoDB’
>   at line 1 1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fixed the issue.
It seems that in the DDL, you can’t say “Type=InnoDB|MyISAM|Foo” anymore. You have to say “Engine=InnoDB|MyISAM”
so edit one file

> symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel-generator/classes/propel/engine/builder
>   /sql/mysql/MysqlDDLBuilder.php
>
> Line 156, change it as follows:-
>    $script
>   .= “Engine=$mysqlTableType”;

Comment: I have the same problem, but your solution doesn't work for me.
I did the changes that you said, but when I do symfony propel:build-all, I've got the same error.
Have I got to compile any file after of do the changes?

Comment: This made my day!  I thought I would have to struggle into tomorrow, but I'm up and running now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A good (better) alternative to manually patching sfPropelPlugin is to [upgrade to Propel 1.5 with the sfPropel15Plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPropel15Plugin). It doesn't have this issue with MySQL 5.5

Comment: Thanks Bhanu, and thank you for documenting your initial issue here.