# Issue with symfony 1.49 and MySQL 5.5.8

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, innodb

when I go to generate the model with `symfony propel:build-sql`
symfony generate a file where after each create sentece adds "Type=InnoDB".
But when I go to insert the tables in the db with `symfony propel:insert-sql`
I've got an error, so I have to change manually "Type=InnoDB" by "Engine=InnoDB"
So, the question: Is there a way to symfony do this change automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question, seems like it has a solution for you — [symfony 1.4 propel:build-all not working on Mysql 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040826/symfony-1-4-propelbuild-all-not-working-on-mysql-5-5)

Comment: I have the same problem, but your solution doesn't work for me. I did the changes that you said, but when I do symfony propel:build-all, I've got the same error. Have I got to compile any file after of do the changes?