# Symfony 1.4.9, doctrine error with schema

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I wrote a schema.yml and tried to build it by

> ./symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation

, but I had syntax error for one table, so I tried to correct the SQL.

After several attempts to correct the SQL and build, I noticed that probably something is wrong, but not with my SQL...

I removed my all shema.yml and wrote a simple table (with only name and Id) and I tried to build it.

I was surprised when I saw... the same syntax error as before!

> - syntax error for table that does not exist in my shema.yml.

Of course I was clear symfony cache.

I don't know what to do...

I look forward to your help

Comment: What is the error you're getting? The error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093373/problem-with-symfony-1-49-and-mysql-5-5-8 has been coming up recently.

Comment: If you deleted some tables from your schema.yml then it doesn't mean that you deleted models.Try do symfony doctrine:clean-model to delete all unnecessary models.

Comment: I used doctrine:clean-model and now it working!