# Symfony: creating invalid MySQL code?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel

I'm reading the Symfony documentation (Practical Symfony), and I finished creating the SQL code with propel.

But when i try to

```
$ symfony propel:insert-sql
```

the MySQL complains with:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Type=InnoDB' at line 7
```

Snippet of the produced MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobeet_category` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `jobeet_category_U_1` ( `name` )
) TYPE = InnoDB;
```

So the problem is TYPE = InnoDB;, but I don't understand why did propel produce invalid code.

I followed all the instructions in the book, I'm not sure what could be the problem - maybe the MySQL version I have?

Edit: I found my answer. http://zippykid.com/2010/05/symfony-mysql5-5-error/

Comment: which version of symfony do you use?

Comment: 1.4.11. But i think I figured it out: http://zippykid.com/2010/05/symfony-mysql5-5-error/

Comment: That was a valid SQL query for MySQL for a the past 10+ years... it's only the very latest major version (5.5.x) that changed `TYPE|ENGINE` to just `ENGINE` in the DDL syntax.

Comment: Some good options over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040826/symfony-1-4-propelbuild-all-not-working-on-mysql-5-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it should be `ENGINE = InnoDB` instead of type.

Comment: Yeah, but what am i supposed to change so that propel produces the correct code?

Comment: You can either manually change it, or downgrade your MySQL version. I don't know if you can upgrade that sympohony/propel thingy to support the newest syntax to be honest.

Comment: Had this problem, ended up just manually editing the `*.sql` file and then re-run `propel:insert-sql`. Ugly but works.