# Why Can't i build my database in symfony using propel orm.?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony1, propel

I am new to the php framework symfony.I have a problem creating the database.I am using propel orm. As usual I made necessary changes in the database.yml page then I edited the schema.yml page. and in order to build the database in the command prompt typed the command..

> c:>php propel:build-all

and i am getting the error message as

> "could not open input
>   file:propel:build-all"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before propel build all in symfony 1.4 . Make an edit in MysqlDDLBuilder.php as mentioned in
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040826/symfony-1-4-propelbuild-all-not-working-on-mysql-5-5)
then Enter project directory in command prompt
and type as below example in my windows system:

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe
>   symfony propel:build-all

Answer (score 1):

Check this link on how to create the sql using propel:

[Building The Database](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/BuildTime#BuildingTheDatabase)

to create the sql use : // will create a sqlfile.sql

> propel-gen sql

then create your database using mysqladmin

> mysqladmin -u root -p create my_db_name

import the sql file

> mysql -u root -p my_db_name < sqlfile.sql